# how to know what category corresponds to each point in a plot in R?

Tags: r

I just wanted how know what category matches with everypoint when I do this:

```
x<-rnorm(mean=0,sd=1,500)
y<-sample(1:500,500,replace=T)
group<-as.factor(sample(c('A','B','C'),500,replace=T,prob=c(0.2,0.3,0.5)))
plot(x,y,col=group)
```

I know how to make a legend and put text with an arbitrary vector c('A','B',C'), but is there a more "automatic" way for doing this? This is an easy example but I need to do it with residuals or survival functions plot

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you're looking for `?legend`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The traditional graphics system provides the `legend` function for adding a
legend or key to a plot. But It should be noted that it is entirely the responsibility of the user to ensure that the legend corresponds to the plot. There is no automatic checking that
data symbols in the legend match those in the plot. It is simpler to do it using `lattice` or `ggplot2`. for example:

```
 library(lattice)
 xyplot(y~x,groups=group,auto.key=T)
```

[image]

if you want absolutly to use base graphics, you can do this :

```
x<-rnorm(mean=0,sd=1,500)
y<-sample(1:500,500,replace=T)
group<-as.factor(sample(c('A','B','C'),500,replace=T,prob=c(0.2,0.3,0.5)))
plot(x,y,col=group,pch=as.numeric(group))

legend(2, 500, c('A','B','C'),
       cex=1.5, pch=1:3,col=1:3)
```

[image]